# Google Pub\Sub Python Client - Gracefully shutdown many subscribers

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-pubsub

I want to create a python script for different pubsub subscriptions, and I need to implement graceful shutdown.

I created the following code to start my subscription process. I want to start it as a server (mainly don't want the script to exit right away). And also allow for graceful shutdown, to avoid problems while handling messages.

I found out we can do this with a single subscription. This code keeps the process running and I believe provide graceful shutdown.

```py
try:
    future = subscriber.subscribe(subscription, callback=call_back)
    future.result()
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    future.cancel()
```

I am not sure how to proceed from the above point. I tried to do the following to be able to wait gracefully for all my subscriptions.

```py
# Create a list to hold subscription futures
subscription_futures = []


def shutdown_handler(signum, frame):
    print("Shutting down gracefully...")

    # Cancel all subscription futures
    for future in subscription_futures:
        print("Cancelling")
        future.cancel()

# register shutdown handler
signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, shutdown_handler)

...

# Subscription Creation
f1 = subscriber.subscribe(subscription_1, callback=call_back1)
f2 = subscriber.subscribe(subscription_2, callback=call_back2)
....

try:
    for future in subscription_futures:
        print("Result")
        future.result()
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    shutdown_handler(signal.SIGINT, None)
```

It seems that "Result" is printed only once, which means the loop is blocked.

This is the output when I press ctrl+c to exit the process.

```bash
Result
Shutting down gracefully...
Cancelling
....many times
Result
... many times
```

How can I proceed from this point ?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you be a little more clear about the issue you are experiencing?

Comment: Okay, I added more details. please check it.